# why the PlusShare.Builder setRecipients method doesn't work?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

In according to [google+ docs](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/prefill#prefill_the_recipients_of_a_post) I'm trying to send post only for defined recipients.

```
Intent sharePost = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setText(msg)
        .setRecipients(Array.asList(PlusShare.createPerson(id, name)))
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"))
        .getIntent();
```

But when the Google+ app is opened the recipients field is not contain priviosly defined persons. I check 'id' and 'name', but they is correct.

May be somebody know something about this. Thanks a lot.

**Update**
this is screenshot of Google+ app after startActivityForResult with current intent. Friends circle set up as share goal.

[image]

**Solution** which based on [Ian's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342384/1326308)

Use [PlusShare.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder.html) which takes two parameters (Activity & PlusClient). But now this constructor is deprecated and maybe exists another solution of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recipients generally can only be prefilled when you are sharing from an app you are signed in to. If you have implemented sign-in in your app, then try the PlusShare.Builder constructor that takes a PlusClient as the second argument.

Comment: @falcon: so what is your solution ? Pls post in here. Thank a lot!

Comment: @falcon - Can you share what you did for setting the recipients? Thanks!

Comment: @TheDevMan, You can see the solution in main post, but it's clear in this answer. Settings is standard, but you need to use constructor that takes a PlusClient.

Comment: According to the docs, the `PlusShare.Builder` constructor only takes a single argument (a `Context` or `Activity`). See the docs here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder

Answer (score 0):

The [setRecipients method](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder.html#setRecipients%28java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person%3E%29) takes an ArrayList, not a Person. Even though you only have one person in your displayed code, it should be in an array list.

```
private ArrayList<Person> recipients;
recipients.add(PlusShare.createPerson(id, name));

Intent sharePost = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setText(msg)
        .setRecipients(recipients)
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"))
        .getIntent();
```

Comment: ups! yep. you're right but it only my miss when i was writing shortest version of my code. one moment and i fix it.

Comment: I fixed my example. So in real code I put List<Person> in the setRecipients method.